# How to get my phonegap ipa file uploaded to the apple app store

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ipa, application-loader

I have successfully built and tested an app using phonegap.  Now I want to upload it to the apple store, but when I run the IPA file through application loader it warns me the bundle id doesnt match what I put into the itunes connect.  Can I configure the bundle id through phonegap or do I have to pull it into xcode and configure it through the info.plist?

What is the easiest way to get my app uploaded to the store with matching information?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get your app into App Store, you will need to create an application (in [App IDs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/index.action)) with the same Bundle Identifier as you presently use in your application..

Also, you will need valid provisioning profile set up for use on the App Store. You'll find this in [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) under [Members Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/). Don't forget to create this profile in the *Distribution* tab and choose the appropriate App ID (the new one you have created).

Then, you will need to download that provisioning profile, drag it into your XCode to install it and use it in Code Signing part under Build Settings.

At last, you will need to visit [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), where you'd create a new application request (under *Manager Your Applications*). Be sure to use the same App ID that you use in your application.

After this, archive your application in XCode (using *Project - Archive* menu item). Make sure your current scheme (top left dropdown) is set for production use, not debug. You can edit your schemes to verify (not sure under which menu it is now).

Last step is to click the archived application and select *Distribute* (or *Share* in older XCode) and choose to export into App Store.

I hope this helps you a bit :)

Comment: Yeah, I have done all of the provisioning steps and ITunes connect the problem was my bundle ID from phonegap didnt match my ITunes connect bundle Id and i didn't know if I could change it in phone gap or had to create a wrapper for it in XCode and then submit.  Sounds like the latter of the two.  Thanks.

Comment: you can simply change the identifier in XCode to match your iTunes connect and it should work just fine ;)

Comment: I think I understand, I was trying to load it through application loader and bypass the xcode process using the IPA file generated from phonegap builder, but I get what your saying.  Thanks